# Convert rows to columns like pivot

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a data like:

```
formid  formownerid approverid
1       100         102
1       100         103
1       100         104
2       200         107
2       200         103
2       200         109
2       200         105
3       400         201
3       400         210
```

I want to convert it to:

```
formid  formownerid approverid  approverid  approverid  approverid
1       100         102         103         104         NULL
2       200         107         103         109         105
3       400         201         202         NULL        NULL
```

Wherever I looked at I saw pivot/unpivot but it looks unrelated since we don't need aggregation.

Comment: because the status was emergency, we coded a func and iterated through. thanks for all answers

Answer (score 4):

The aggregate is a necessary part of the pivot, but it's simple to apply here; you don't want `sum` but a `max` aggregate works fine:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by formid, formownerid
      order by approverid) as rn
  from t42 t
)
pivot (max(approverid) as approverid for (rn) in (1, 2, 3, 4));

    FORMID FORMOWNERID 1_APPROVERID 2_APPROVERID 3_APPROVERID 4_APPROVERID
---------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
         1         100          102          103          104              
         2         200          103          105          107          109 
         3         400          201          210
```

Or you can specify the column name prefix explicitly to make them valid identifiers:

```
pivot (max(approverid) as approverid
  for (rn) in (1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c, 4 as d));
```

The inner query is adding a pseudocolumn `rn` to the table results to give you a fixed value to pivot against, since the actual approver IDs aren't going to be known in advance.

The manual approach might make this a bit clearer:

```
select formid, formownerid,
  max(case when rn = 1 then approverid end) as approverid_1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then approverid end) as approverid_2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then approverid end) as approverid_3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then approverid end) as approverid_4
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by formid, formownerid
      order by approverid) as rn
  from t42 t
)
group by formid, formownerid
order by formid, formownerid;

    FORMID FORMOWNERID APPROVERID_1 APPROVERID_2 APPROVERID_3 APPROVERID_4
---------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
         1         100          102          103          104              
         2         200          103          105          107          109 
         3         400          201          210
```

The inner query is the same. The `case` statement produces each column as above, but without the `max` and grouping you get multiple rows with lots of extra blanks:

```
select formid, formownerid,
  case when rn = 1 then approverid end as approverid_1,
  case when rn = 2 then approverid end as approverid_2,
  case when rn = 3 then approverid end as approverid_3,
  case when rn = 4 then approverid end as approverid_4
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by formid, formownerid
      order by approverid) as rn
  from t42 t
);

    FORMID FORMOWNERID APPROVERID_1 APPROVERID_2 APPROVERID_3 APPROVERID_4
---------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
         1         100          102                                        
         1         100                       103                           
         1         100                                    104              
         2         200          103                                        
         2         200                       105                           
         2         200                                    107              
         2         200                                                 109 
         3         400          201                                        
         3         400                       210
```

Notice that there's only a value in (at most) one column for each `formid`/`formownerid` combination, but that they appear in different rows. The `max` suppresses those multiple rows; and the pivot version does something similar under the hood.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4d56/1) showing the manual approach with the intermediate step, and the pivot version.

Comment: thanks and i guess it works but we had trouble in oracle object pivot somehow and because the status is emergency, we did it hardway and iterated through. and also appended the strings(on approver column) thanks anyway.

Comment: @Doruk - pivot wasn't available until 11g, so if you're on an earlier version then it would 'object'. The max/case version works on earlier versions though.

Answer (score -2):

One possible Approch:

```
SELECT FROMID, FROMOWNERID, APPROVERID, NULL APPROVERID, NULL APPROVERID, NULL APPROVERID
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  FROMID = 100
AND    APPROVERID =  102
UNION ALL
SELECT FROMID, FROMOWNERID, NULL APPROVERID, APPROVERID APPROVERID, NULL APPROVERID, NULL APPROVERID
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  FROMID = 100
AND    APPROVERID =  103
UNION ALL
SELECT FROMID, FROMOWNERID, NULL APPROVERID, NULL APPROVERID, APPROVERID APPROVERID, NULL APPROVERID
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  FROMID = 100
AND    APPROVERID =  104
----
-------
And So On
```

Comment: we're talking about a big data. we cant write ids'

Comment: I suggest PLSQL,  Pipelined functions